# Dagger2 Qualifier/Named provider with constructor injection

Tags: java, dagger-2

I have two classes: `Foo` and `Bar`. `Foo` depends on `Bar`.
There are two singleton instances of `Bar`:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("first")
static Bar provideFirstBar() {
    return new Bar();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("second")
static Bar provideSecondBar() {
    return new Bar();
}
```

and also two singleton instances of `Foo` (each depends of relevant `Bar`).

```
@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("first")
static Foo provideFirstFoo(@Named("first") Bar bar) {
    return new Foo(bar);
}

@Singleton
@Provides
@Named("second")
static Foo provideSecondFoo(@Named("second") Bar bar) {
    return new Foo(bar);
}
```

Now, the problem: I'd like to simplify this module and get rid of `provide*Foo` methods, instead use constructor dependency for `Foo`. I know how to do it if I need `@Named("first")` instance only:

```
@Singleton
@Named("first")
class Foo {
    @Inject
    Foo(Bar bar) { }
}
```

But is it possible to use both: `@Named` instances and constructor injection for all possible names? Or I should stay with the `@Provider` methods?

Answer (score 0):

I have asked this question before and always been told no. You are unable to have named/qualifier annotations with constructor injections.